# Facebook API get recent checkins to location/page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know who checked in my bar in the last few hours,
is there a way to get a list of recent check ins to my facebook page (or location) ? get the list of images / posts / user ids ?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page
only checkins count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don´t think its possible to get a list of checkins, for privacy reasons. Even the `user_checkins` permission got removed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions